# Undefined reference to boost::filesystem

Tags: c++, ubuntu, boost, linker

Since I am new to boost. I have made a mistake. I used the command to **sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev** to overcome some errors but after that it seems like I have done something really bad. Now there are a lot of errors as following:

```
error: undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::remove_all(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'

error: undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::path::filename() const'

error: undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::create_directory(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'
```

And a lot mroe like these errors all stating undefined references. After reading and trying some solutions prvided related to same issue I still got no success. but I have come across a kind of clue that when I run **dpkg -s libboost-dev | grep 'Version'** it gives *Version: 1.48.0.2* but when I run

**cat /usr/include/boost/version.hpp | grep "BOOST_LIB_VERSION"** it gives me

BOOST_LIB_VERSION must be defined to be the same as BOOST_VERSION

define BOOST_LIB_VERSION "1_46_1

I have also tried linking -lboost::system and -lboost::filesystem as well but the errors are still there. Could it be the problem because of two different versions ? 
Can someone tell me what should I do in this situation before proceeding any further and makig some more mistakes ? 
what if I remove *Version: 1.48.0.2* and try again .. someone has done something like this before ? or any suggestions/comments ?

your help will be much appreciated.

Thanks :)

p.s I am using QT creator with clang++

**EDIT**

After installing libraries with ./b2 and bootstrap.sh this is what I am getting:

The Boost C++ Libraries were successfully built!

The following directory should be added to compiler include paths:

```
/home/black/workspace/cap/lib/boost_1_53_0
```

The following directory should be added to linker library paths:

```
/home/black/workspace/cap/lib/boost_1_53_0/stage/lib
```

I have added these paths to a lot of places e.g lib path to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH, PATH` etc and include path to `C_INCLUDE_PATH` .. Also I added these to `INCLUDEPATH` in my .pro file and to `LIBS` as well .. but nothing is working :(
is it correct or am I doing something wrong ? 
can you please tell me where should these paths be added ?

Comment: Can you please show us your build-scripts?

Comment: I believe you are linking incorrectly. You should be linking to `-lboost_filesystem -lboost_system` and don't forget to add `-L{path to boost libraries}`

Comment: I tried the same thing as you have mentioned but its not working.

Comment: Could you compile this example http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/filesystem/example/tut1.cpp and post your compile command and output?

Comment: main.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0': /usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:214: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()' /usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:215: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()' /usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:216: undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()' 

...obviously it is not complete error, I can not post it all here because of limitation of characters

Comment: main.o: In function `boost::filesystem3::path::codecvt()':
/usr/include/boost/filesystem/v3/path.hpp:377: undefined reference to `boost::filesystem3::path::wchar_t_codecvt_facet()'
main.o: In function `boost::filesystem3::file_size(boost::filesystem3::path const&)':
/usr/include/boost/filesystem/v3/operations.hpp:366: undefined reference to `boost::filesystem3::detail::file_size(boost::filesystem3::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [practice] Error 1
10:42:24: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.

Comment: You need to show your exact, unedited build commands ("I just did what you suggested" isn't it).